# How to get this OCR model to work with variable length examples?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, ocr, captcha

This is a modified version of the OCR [example](https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/) in keras docs. First you'll need to download the input data which is a folder containing 1000 photos that have fixed length (5) captchas.

```
curl -LO https://github.com/AakashKumarNain/CaptchaCracker/raw/master/captcha_images_v2.zip
unzip -qq captcha_images_v2.zip
```

This my version which needs adjustment

```
from pathlib import Path

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (LSTM, Bidirectional, Conv2D, Dense,
                                     Dropout, Input, Layer, MaxPooling2D,
                                     Reshape)
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import StringLookup


class TrainManager:
    def __init__(self, src, image_width=200, image_height=50, batch_size=16):
        src = Path(src)
        self.image_width = image_width
        self.image_height = image_height
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.images = []
        self.labels = []
        for image in src.glob('*.png'):
            self.labels.append(image.stem)
            self.images.append(image.as_posix())
        self.max_label_length = len(max(self.labels, key=len))
        self.characters = sorted(set(''.join(self.labels)))
        self.char_to_num = StringLookup(vocabulary=self.characters, mask_token=None)
        self.num_to_char = StringLookup(
            vocabulary=self.char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, invert=True
        )

    def encode_sample(self, img_path, label):
        img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
        img = tf.io.decode_png(img, channels=1)
        img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
        img = tf.image.resize(img, [self.image_height, self.image_width])
        img = tf.transpose(img, perm=[1, 0, 2])
        label = self.char_to_num(
            tf.strings.unicode_split(label, input_encoding='UTF-8')
        )
        return {'image': img, 'label': label}

    def create_dataset(self, x, y, batch_size):
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
        return (
            dataset.map(self.encode_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
            .batch(batch_size)
            .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
        )

    def create_datasets(self, train_size=0.9, shuffle=True):
        images, labels = np.array(self.images), np.array(self.labels)
        size = len(images)
        indices = np.arange(size)
        if shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(indices)
        train_samples = int(size * train_size)
        x_train, y_train = (
            images[indices[:train_samples]],
            labels[indices[:train_samples]],
        )
        x_valid, y_valid = (
            images[indices[train_samples:]],
            labels[indices[train_samples:]],
        )
        train_dataset = self.create_dataset(x_train, y_train, self.batch_size)
        valid_dataset = self.create_dataset(x_valid, y_valid, self.batch_size)
        return train_dataset, valid_dataset

    def display_dataset(self, dataset, n_rows=1, n_cols=1, fig_size=(10, 5)):
        _, ax = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols, figsize=fig_size)
        for batch in dataset.take(1):
            images = batch['image']
            labels = batch['label']
            for i in range(n_rows * n_cols):
                img = (images[i] * 255).numpy().astype('uint8')
                label = (
                    tf.strings.reduce_join(self.num_to_char(labels[i]))
                    .numpy()
                    .decode('utf-8')
                )
                row = i // n_rows
                col = i % n_cols
                ax[row, col].imshow(img[:, :, 0].T, cmap='gray')
                ax[row, col].set_title(label)
                ax[row, col].axis('off')

    def create_model(self, training=True):
        x0 = Input(
            shape=(self.image_width, self.image_height, 1),
            name='image',
            dtype='float32',
        )
        x = Conv2D(
            32,
            (3, 3),
            activation='relu',
            kernel_initializer='he_normal',
            padding='same',
            name='Conv1',
        )(x0)
        x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='pool1')(x)
        x = Conv2D(
            64,
            (3, 3),
            activation='relu',
            kernel_initializer='he_normal',
            padding='same',
            name='Conv2',
        )(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='pool2')(x)
        new_shape = ((self.image_width // 4), (self.image_height // 4) * 64)
        x = Reshape(target_shape=new_shape, name='reshape')(x)
        x = Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense1')(x)
        x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
        x = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))(x)
        x = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))(x)
        x = Dense(
            len(self.char_to_num.get_vocabulary()) + 1,
            activation='softmax',
            name='dense2',
        )(x)
        if not training:
            return Model(x0, x)
        labels = Input(name='label', shape=(None,), dtype='float32')
        output = CTCLayer(name='ctc_loss')(labels, x)
        model = Model(inputs=[x0, labels], outputs=output, name='ocr_model_v1')
        return model

    def decode_batch_predictions(self, pred):
        input_len = np.ones(pred.shape[0]) * pred.shape[1]
        results = tf.keras.backend.ctc_decode(
            pred, input_length=input_len, greedy=True
        )[0][0][:, : self.max_label_length]
        output_text = []
        for result in results:
            result = (
                tf.strings.reduce_join(self.num_to_char(result)).numpy().decode('utf-8')
            )
            output_text.append(result)
        return output_text


class CTCLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.loss_fn = tf.keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost

    def call(self, y_true, *args, **kwargs):
        y_pred = args[0]
        batch_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype='int64')
        input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype='int64')
        label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype='int64')
        input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_length, 1), dtype='int64')
        label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_length, 1), dtype='int64')
        loss = self.loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
        self.add_loss(loss)
        return y_pred


def main():
    w, h = 200, 50
    manager = TrainManager('captcha_images_v2', w, h)
    print('Number of images found: ', len(manager.images))
    print('Number of labels found: ', len(manager.labels))
    print('Number of unique characters: ', len(manager.characters))
    print('Characters present: ', manager.characters)
    optimizer = Adam()
    m = manager.create_model()
    m.compile(optimizer)
    m.summary()
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
        monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True
    )
    tr_dataset, val_dataset = manager.create_datasets()
    history = m.fit(
        tr_dataset,
        validation_data=val_dataset,
        epochs=100,
        callbacks=[early_stopping],
    )
```

It works perfectly fine for fixed lengths captchas and **note** the names of the files `2b827.png, 2bg48.png, 2cegf.png, ...` are the labels contained in their respective images.

[image: c1]
[image: c2]
[image: c3]

If I modify `2b827.png` to `2b827abcde.png`, I'll get the following error:

```
2021-10-12 09:14:41.276269: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
Epoch 1/100
18/59 [========>.....................] - ETA: 8s - loss: 29.0998Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/ocr_example.py", line 216, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/ocr_example.py", line 179, in main
    history = m.fit(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1184, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 885, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 917, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3039, in __call__
    return graph_function._call_flat(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1963, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 591, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [10], [batch]: [5]
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:841) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_11873]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node IteratorGetNext:
 iterator (defined at usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:1184)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I need to modify it to accept and output variable lengths inputs/outputs. I think the inputs need to be padded respective to the longest label contained in the dataset.

Here's an example to illustrate what I think may work: given we have `abc.png`, `abcde.png`, and `abcdefghij.png`, inputs as well as possible outputs, they should have a form similar to:

- `abc.png`
- `abcde.png`
- `abcdefghij.png`

But this approach will be limited to examples of length 10. I expect problems for longer than 10 labels. An ideal solution should accept any length and output any length as well. Here's an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40919) addressing the very same problem, which was resolved by padding the labels which I think has unforeseen shortcomings for the same reasons I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

So, let's assume you want to use different, longer labels than your current ones, which have a fix length of 5 as I can see when printing the `max_length`:

```
max_length = max([len(label) for label in labels])
# 5
```

You then need to adjust your functions `def encode_sample(self, img_path, label)` and `create_dataset(self, x, y, batch_size)` so that the labels are shorter than or equals to the maximum length, which can be arbitrary. Here, I am assuming a `max_length=20` and that 0 is reserved as the padding character:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
max_length = 20
for data in train_dataset:
  x,y = data
  data_dict = encode_single_sample(x, y)
  difference = max_length -  data_dict['label'].shape[0]
  if difference != 0:
    padding = np.zeros(difference)
    data_dict['label'] = np.concatenate((data_dict['label'], padding))
```

I think you get the idea. Note that you may also need to adjust your input shapes in your model. If you want to avoid padding this way, you only need to make sure that each individual batch, i.e. all labels in that batch, have the same shape. During inference you can have any length if your input shape remains `shape=(None,)`.

Comment: I think this will solve the problem as I mentioned in the question earlier. The problem is when presented with an unseen length example in this case > 20, will it output 50 letters for a captcha that has 50 letters?

Comment: Also by `you may also need to adjust your  input shapes in your model`, do you mean I need to pad the images too? ex: for the label `0000abc.png`, should the image contain 4 zeros?

Comment: I was referring to your label input shape (not your images themselves), if you use padding, you will probably define your label input as follows: `tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_length,))`

Comment: Are you referring to *L. 126:* `labels = Input(name='label', shape=(None,), dtype='float32')` which has to be explicitly specified as `shape=(max_length,)`?

Comment: Regarding your first question: Since you have defined your label input with `shape=(None,)`, you only need to make sure that each individual batch, i.e. all labels in that batch, have the same shape. During inference you can have any length if your input shape remains `shape=(None,)`.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to *L. 126*, but you only have to change it if you start using padding across all batches.

Comment: My main concern is making this work with images containing text of any length. Do you think this can be achieved by doing only these modifications? Should I make any modifications to the images? I mean if the max length is 10 and I have a label of length 3, should I add 7 spaces or zeros in the image? I'm asking because if I did not, how the model is expected to conclude that the 3 length captcha has 7 spaces or zeros from the image?